# Issue with mail sending using openURL

Tags: iphone, html, email, openurl

I'm facing a issue with opening mail client using openURL. Here is the code.

```
NSString *subject = @"Demo Subject";
NSString *body = @"<html><head>Header</head><body><a href=\"http://example.com\">Here is the demo link</a></body></html>";
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:?&subject=%@&body=%@",subject,body];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

I guess, is there any kind of encoding needed to use special characters, which is do present, but not shown here in the sample text.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSString *htmlBody = @"you probably want something HTML-y here";

// First escape the body using a CF call
NSString *escapedBody = [(NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,  (CFStringRef)htmlBody, NULL,  CFSTR("?=&+"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];

// Then escape the prefix using the NSString method
NSString *mailtoPrefix = [@"mailto:?subject=Some Subject&body=" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Finally, combine to create the fully escaped URL string
NSString *mailtoStr = [mailtoPrefix stringByAppendingString:escapedBody];

// And let the application open the merged URL
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mailtoStr]];
```

Comment: Chetu, thanx, it worked...here I just tried NSUTF8StringEncoding for entire urlString of openURL. Will it make any difference if that CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes is used?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [[mail navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        [mail setSubject:@"Demo Subject"];
        [mail setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"me"]];
        [mail setMessageBody:@"<html><head>Header</head><body><a href=\"http://example.com\">Here is the demo link</a></body></html>" isHTML:YES];
        [self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
    }
    [mail release];
```

instead of openURL

Comment: thanx for the response, I've used that way but since we have to explicitly dismiss mail composer, I'm just trying an alternate way out.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *subject = @"Demo Subject";
NSString *body = @"<html><head>Header</head><body><a href=\"http://example.com\">Here is the demo link</a></body></html>";
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:?subject=%@&body=%@",subject,body];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

I change in this line check it, and compare it...

```
 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:?subject=%@&body=%@",subject,body];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of [`MFMailComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) for this. That can help you to support special characters by using this method

```
- (void)setMessageBody:(NSString*)body isHTML:(BOOL)isHTML
```

ie

```
[yourMailPicker setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

tried your code and got the problem  [NSURL URLWithString:urlString] this line returns nil.

Comment: Yes, it will, that is my issue, as @Love Chetu said, just follow the steps to encode it.I prefer to use CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes for both subject and body, then set urlString.