# Encode mailto: uri

Tags: c#, ios, encoding, xamarin.ios, mailto

I have to send mails from a `Xamarin.iOS` application using `OpenUrl`. Simple cases works fine:

```
var uri = new Uri ("mailto:info@example.com");
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (new NSUrl (uri.ToString ()));
```

But if I'd like to send compilex `mailto` uri, with subject e.g., it require some kind of encoding.

```
var uri = new Uri ("mailto:info@example.com?subject=Hello, World!");
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (new NSUrl (uri.ToString ())); //FAIL
```

I've tried `System.Net.Webutility.Encode()` but that doesn't work.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172664/issue-with-mail-sending-using-openurl.

Answer (score 1):

`WebUtility.UrlEncode` **does** work. But `NSUrl` input is limited.

I fixed this by stripping the strange characters out of the input string.

```
var subject = Regex.Replace (subject, @"[^\u0000-\u00FF]", string.Empty);
var uri = new Uri("mailto:info@b4c.be?subject=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(subject));
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (new NSUrl (uri.ToString ()));
```

Comment: Take note that `NSUrl` is more strict in iOS7+ than it was before (so old, tested code might not work as expected).